# Need help getting proper indentation for sections and sub-sections

Tags: html, css

To quickly understand the problem I'm having, first take a quick look at the comparison pic below, which shows the indentation effect I want to achieve versus what I'm actually getting.

I am trying to get all lines in each sub-section to line-up on their first character of text content, *indented past the space taken-up by the section notation*.

I believe this is similar to a hanging indent, except it is smarter be cause it knows the string-length of each section notation and adjusts accordingly. I'm not sure what the proper name of this effect is (if there is one).

I've already tried to use `text-indent`and other properties, without success.   The text is a ordered list with sub-items.
When enumerated as `1.1.2` or `1.1` the text indentation/alignment is not achieved as described above.
[image]

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
    display: block;
}

li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<div class ="all-text">
  <div align="center" ><b>TITLE</b></div>
  <br><br>
  <div class ="lista-principal">  <!-- div da lista ordenada principal -->
  <ol> <!-- Lista ordenada principal -->
  <!-- Inicio do ITEM 1 da lista principal P1 -->
    <li> <span>TITULO</span> 
        <ol> 
           <li>
            But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <!-- Fim do ITEM 1 da lista principal P1 -->

    <!-- Inicio do ITEM 2 da lista principal P1 -->
    <li>
      <span>OBJETO</span>
      <ol>
          <li>
           At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
        </li>
        <li>
            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
        </li>
        <li>
            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
        </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
<!-- Fim do ITEM 2 da lista principal P1 -->
</ol> <!-- FIM da lista ordenada principal -->
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: I don't know the word for the effect either, but I think this explains the problem pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

This code work for me:

css

```
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

ol ol li{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class ="all-text">
  <div align="center" ><b>TITLE</b></div>
  <br><br>
  <div class ="lista-principal">  <!-- div da lista ordenada principal -->
  <ol> <!-- Lista ordenada principal -->
  <!-- Inicio do ITEM 1 da lista principal P1 -->
    <li> <span>TITULO</span> 
        <ol> 
           <li>
            But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <!-- Fim do ITEM 1 da lista principal P1 -->

    <!-- Inicio do ITEM 2 da lista principal P1 -->
    <li>
      <span>OBJETO</span>
      <ol>
          <li>
           At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
        </li>
        <li>
            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
        </li>
        <li>
            At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga.
        </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
<!-- Fim do ITEM 2 da lista principal P1 -->
</ol> <!-- FIM da lista ordenada principal -->
```